# How can I get HINSTANCE from a DLL?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have created a DLL in VC++ as Win32 project

DLLMAIN function is

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Now I need HINSTANCE of the DLL , that need to be passed to Win32 functions.

Are HMODULE and HINSTANCE same?

How can I get HINSTANCE?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An excerpt from the book Windows Via C/C++ [1]

> **Note** As it turns out, **HMODULE**s and **HINSTANCE**s are exactly the same thing. If the documentation for a function indicates that an **HMODULE** is required, you can pass an **HINSTANCE** and vice versa. There are two data types because in 16-bit Windows **HMODULE**s and **HINSTANCE**s identified different things

[1] Richter, Jeffery and Nasarre, Christophe, *Windows Via C/C++*, 5th ed, Redmond: Microsoft Press 2008, pp. 74

Comment: Win32, HINSTANCE and HMODULE are both just the base address of the module.

Answer (score 5):

I think that these are the same. If you want HINSTANCE of the running process (exe), you should use

```
GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

Comment: This does not return the `HMODULE` of a **DLL**, which is what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft linker specific

```
#include "windows.h"
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#pragma warning(disable: 4047)
HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase;
#pragma warning(default: 4047)
```

Comment: What if the DLL is relocated?

Answer (score 2):

Calling GetModuleHandle(NULL) from a dll will return the Hinstanc of the EXE that started the DLL; to get the Hinstance for the curently running dll try this tip:

[http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/13/65259.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20120322043832/http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/13/65259.aspx)

Comment: The linked website has been taken down.  Here is another useful article on the same topic: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/tips/article.php/c3635

Answer (score 1):

DllMain function as it's described in MSDN:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  __in  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  __in  DWORD fdwReason,
  __in  LPVOID lpvReserved
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Each DLL has at least a header file, say MyDll.h and a corresponding implementation file MyDll.cpp. Open the header file and add

```
extern HMODULE hDllModule;//or whatever name you like
```

Now open the MyDll.cpp file. There is a function DLLMAIN. Add before it `HMODULE hDllModule;` and insert `hDllModuleDll = hModule;` before `return true;`. Your code will look like this:

```
HMODULE hDllModuleDll;
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
  hDllModuleDll = hModule;
  return TRUE;
}
```

In functions like `::GetModuleFileNameW(hModule, PathFile, MAX_PATH);` that require a `HMODULE` of the DLL you can pass the global variable `hDllModule`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers, for the sake of completness.

The actual signature of `DllMain` has an `HINSTANCE` parameter, instead of a `HMODULE` parameter. The Visual Studio DLL template generates the signature with `HMODULE` since at least Visual Studio 2008 however, but I believe this to be a minor bug more than anything. VC6 generated the code with `HANDLE` (even though both `HINSTANCE` and `HMODULE` exist). The reason that doesn't cause problems is because [`HINSTANCE` and `HMODULE` are now exactly the same thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903). Unfortunately I was unable to find an ancient enough version of the MSDN documetnation that could have confirmed this.

So the answer is: **You get your `HINSTANCE` as an argument to your `DllMain`.**

Personally I sort of like the distinction between HMODULE and HINSTANCE because it appeals to me as being good code hygiene. It's a bit like using `const`. But then, a new question arises: **Given your `HINSTANCE`, how do you get your `HMODULE`** in the "hygienic" way?

The `windowsx.h` header defines `GetInstanceModule`, which is now a macro that just casts the `HINSTANCE` to `HMODULE`. It only exists for code compatibility, along with a bunch of very similar macros.