# C++ .dll files what exactly can they be used for and how to create them

Tags: c++, dll, codeblocks

i have been doing some looking at dlls. what exactly are all the uses of dlls...can they be used to store graphics? im guessing the main way to use them is to store code...or am i wrong? how do you go about creating dlls(with source and graphics? if possible).
any help would be appreciated.
i am using Code::Blocks ide with mingW compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, DLLs are meant for holding execution code.

However they can be used to embed images, using [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx) in Visual C++ but I don't think it's possible with Code::Blocks.

To create a DLL with Code::Blocks, simply create a new project with template "Dynamic Link Library".

Comment: IIRC, you can have a data-only DLL.

Comment: great thanks for the help...how would u go about creating a dll...that can hold resources with visual studio?

Comment: @IPhantasmI: [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=visual+c%2B%2B+resource) is [your friend](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1074362/11343)

Answer (score 3):

`dll` - ***dynamic link library***, refers to a ***shared library*** on microsoft platforms.

You should check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) out and that should clarify your basically flawed understanding of what an `dll` is..